# Potential bluetooth connection malware

Tags: bluetooth, malware, virus

I tried to disconnect and remove this device called '57-14-cf-5d-3c-62', and it doesn't work. I'm not really sure why, but I'm wondering if this is potential malware. If so, what is the best way to check and remove it?

[image]

Comment: is this software or a hardware device?

Comment: It is a Software device

Comment: It looks like a MAC address.  Where did you see it?

What is the output of 
`sudo find / -name "57-14-cf-5d-3c-62" -print`
?

Comment: @WGroleau "No such file or directory".

Comment: We have a communication problem.  `find` never says "No such file or directory" unless your path variable is wrong.

Comment: Put your command in quotes please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't REMOVE it, as long as your Mac can hear the broadcast from this device, it will be listed there in the Preference Pane.

It's harmless, a BT device can't force a connection, you have to accept the pairing request.

Comment: Ok. Strange that it just appears there, even if my other friends’ Macs don’t have that listed...

Comment: BT is short range.  You're within range, they aren't... your antenna is oriented to receive it, theirs isn't... your BT is turned on, theirs isn't... lots of reasons.

Comment: And strangely enough, a restart doesn’t help. Oh well, I’ll live with it or fix the steps until my future Mac…